# How to fix Apple Mach -O-linker warning Directory is not found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, error-handling, linker-errors

I am facing this warning in `Xcode 5.1`.
How to fix this error

Here the Error is Showing like...

```
Ld /Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SedioiOS.app/SedioiOS normal i386
        cd /Users/riz/Desktop/vine-clone-iphone/SedioiOS
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Intermediates/SedioiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SedioiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/SedioiOS.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -lz.1.2.5 -lz -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreVideo -framework MobileCoreServices -framework ImageIO -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MediaPlayer -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Intermediates/SedioiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SedioiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/SedioiOS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/riz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SedioiOS-dfvlolozvfewogempmjncnwobvbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SedioiOS.app/SedioiOS

----------


`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks'`
```

Comment: What have you done so far, and what code causes the error? Did you try googling the error and the warning messages?

Comment: u have change any folder or filename or change any name of the file or change any frame work path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this **`$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)`** on Framework Search Paths in Build Settings..

Check the Screenshot Image.. maybe its helpful to you..

then clean,build and run..

[image: Framework Search Paths]

Comment: It looks like the OP already has that (in some form) as that is the linker option causing the error.